# Unique ID script field calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, unique-id

I need to generate a unique id using field calculator in ArcMap. I am a student and I am having problems finding the script or getting auto increment to work or anything else.

Comment: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/91465

Comment: if you have a geodatabase(no matter personal or SDE) you can use ArcToolBox and add GlobalId field to your table.It simply adds a unique id to your table.If you insist to use field calculator,you have to provide a code block in VB script or python for it.They don't have any ready to use function to generate unique id except you have a SDE SQL server database,in this case you can have a Guid field in your table and use NewId() (a function declared in SQL server) in field calculator(but not usable in personal geodatabase).

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to create a quick python script to auto increment through values. In the field calculator, set the `Parser` to `Python`. Click `Show Codeblock`. In your `Pre-Logic Script Code` block, use:

```
def UID ():
 global i
 try:
  i += 1
 except:
  i = 1
 try:
  return i
 except:
  return str(i)
```

Then in your field calculator, just type:

```
UID ()
```

[image: Field_Calculator]

If you need to start over, click the Python window button on the `Standard` toolbar, and type `del i`.
[image: Start_Over]

Comment: you need just set i=0 or other value before def. del i isn't necessary